# Location Notification's based on Latest iOS Feature

Tags: ios, ios8, mapkit, cllocationmanager, geofencing

I would like to know whether the following is implementable ?

I want my iOS app to give users a notification when the reach a particular location as set in the app (even if the app is killed)

Comment: No. But you might get to a similar experience with iBeacons.

Comment: This is called Geo-fencing and no this is not a latest iOS Feature, has been there for a long time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with the new User Notification framework introduced in iOS 10.

There have a `UNLocationNotificationTrigger` which let you specify a `CLRegion`. A notification will be post when the user’s device enters or leaves the `CLRegion`. Use the `CLRegion` object to specify whether to deliver notifications on entry, on exit, or both.

Refer to:

UserNotifications framework:

https://developer.apple.com/reference/usernotifications

UNLocationNotificationTrigger:

https://developer.apple.com/reference/usernotifications/unlocationnotificationtrigger

Answer (score 1):

When the app is killed you can't , but you can still do it in background mode.

Comment: Is that the new iOS 8 feature?

Comment: iBeacons ? No. " iBeacon is a low-cost transmitters that can notify nearby iOS 7 devices (and above) of their presence"

Comment: Okay... I'm talking about a new feature/functionality of iOS which allows users to get notifications when the arraive at a location

Comment: SO as i say if your app is killed you can't do it

Comment: to get the userLocation in background mode check this : http://www.raywenderlich.com/29948/backgrounding-for-ios

Comment: What about Geofencing? Is my idea similar to it?

Comment: Yes, geofencing! Basically you have to monitor regions and when you did enter or exit, notify the user. See apple's documentation about it. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/RegionMonitoring/RegionMonitoring.html

Comment: How to implement Geofencing with minimal power consumption?

I want my app to notify user when he/she is near the location pointed by the MapKit even if the app is not running.....

Please help

Answer (score 1):

**First Way:**
UNLocationNotificationTrigger notifies user when user enters the specified location or exit the specified location [this link](https://developer.apple.com/reference/usernotifications/unlocationnotificationtrigger) provides exact implementation.

**Second Way:**
[monitoring significant changes](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html) can do this for you but the result may not be 100%.
call following method from `applicationDidEnterBackground` and `applicationWillTerminate:`;

```
- (void)startSignificantChangeUpdates
{
    // Create the location manager if this object does not
    // already have one.
    if (nil == locationManager)
        locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];

    locationManager.delegate = self;
    [locationManager startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];
}
```

and when app enters foreground `applicationWillEnterForeground:` call following method (modify it as per your requirements i.e. accuracy & distance filter)

```
- (void)startStandardUpdates
{
    // Create the location manager if this object does not
    // already have one.
    if (nil == locationManager)
        locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];

    locationManager.delegate = self;
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyKilometer;

    // Set a movement threshold for new events.
    locationManager.distanceFilter = 500; // meters

    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}
```

**From apple documentation:**
*The significant-change location service delivers updates only when there has been a significant change in the device’s location, such as 500 meters or more. It’s crucial that you use the significant-change location service correctly, because it wakes the system and your app at least every 15 minutes, even if no location changes have occurred, and it runs continuously until you stop it.*

For 100% accuracy you can involve server end and send silent notifications from server which will give your application a 30 second window to determine user location and fire a local notification.